# Google Drive Sdk .net upload and download

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have a big problem, my customer wants to send files in google drive. Both upload and download. I checked everywhere but I can't see how. Can you help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at the [Google Drive SDK .NET Client example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet).

Comment: Thank you. I read it. But I can't do it.Please help me?

Comment: What have you done so far. Please see @yanshof response which has helpful links to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I check now!